# Android Studio unit testing with LibGDX test folder missing Arctic Fox

Tags: java, android-studio, unit-testing

I've not used Android Studio in a while and have forgotten more things about it than I ever knew.

I am working with LibGDX and have some complicated class/methods I'd like to do unit testing on them outside of the graphic environment. On a normal android project, I'd have a structure that looks something like:
app
manifests
java
com.example.myApplication
MainActivity
ClassToTest
com.example.myApplication (test)
ClassToTestUnitTest

But when I generate a LibGDX my structure looks like:
Android
manifests
java
com.example.myApplication
MainActivity
ClassToTest

When I go to 'Generate...' 'Tests' by right clicking on the ClassToTest entry in the java file, I receive the message 'Create test in the same root?'

**No**, I don't want that - I want to have a special folder for tests to be contained away from my main code.

How do I create that folder and have the test generator know where it is?? All the answers I could find looked like they were created for a much older version of Android Studio, since the folder hierarchy was different.

In further looking, it appeared I needed to make some changes to my code build.gradle. I tried the changes suggested, but there was no effect that I could see.

The gradle now looks like:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["test/"]

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-core"
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide. I am sure I am missing something fairly basic.